# Reporter: Contact duration and gap times

Tags: netlogo

I'm struggling with this for the past week... I would like to build three reporters (so I can extract these info) of:

- The duration of contacts between pairs of agents (i and j).
- The gap between consecutive contacts between pairs of agents (i and j).
- Number of contacts that an agent has.

If you can give a (small) push in the right direction, I would be grateful!

Comment: What is a "contact"?  (E.g., a shared patch?)  Is contact duration measured in ticks?  You could make a table that maps each pair to a list of the ticks counted as contacts, and then process the lists for the rest of the info.

Comment: Thank you: yes, duration measured in ticks. A contact is that they stand together still after an action. I was thinking of a list. I have not checked table yet. Is there something available on the table code in netlogo.

Comment: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html
hth

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure it out. It is a bit cryptic.

Comment: Use of the extension shd quickly become clear with use.  If not, open a new question.  Someone will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpreted this correctly, this is something I would probably do with links (though the table suggestion by @Alan may be quicker). Create a link between pairs of agents as they make contact and the link can have attributes such as duration, time (tick) of previous contact, maximum time between contacts, number of contacts.

The problem is that the number of ties is going to be N(N-1)/2 where N is number of agents. For large N, I suspect this would be fairly slow, at least to create the links. If you are expecting a dense network, with most agents contacting each other, then create all the links during setup and simply update the attributes. If a sparse network, with each agent contacting only a limited number of others, create the link at initial contact.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Im trying to solve this puzzle.